# In Prolog, how to represent a(X) => b(X) V c(X)?

Tags: prolog

I think it is: `(b(X); c(X)) :- a(X).`

But it will show error:
ERROR:    No permission to modify static procedure `(;)/2'
ERROR:    Defined at c:/program files/swipl/boot/init.pl:320

I just couldn't find the right syntax.

Comment: You don't. Prolog is not *answer set programming*. The syntax consists out of *horn clauses*.

Comment: What do you mean by "You don't"? Do you mean that a(X) => b(X) V c(X) can't be expressed in prolog? Or there is a way?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you even do that in ASP?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: yes, see section 7 of http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cmartens/asp-notes.pdf or exercise 7 of http://web.stanford.edu/~vinayc/logicprogramming/html/answer_set_programming.html Of course not all (simple) ASP solvers will *per se* support this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks. This is so great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot express this in old-school Prolog.

You can only write programs consisting of Horn Clauses, which have a positive head and either an empty (in case of a fact) or nonempty (in case of a rule) body.

```
q(X).
b(X) :- a(X).
```

These are ok. Anything else is undefined.

Though having it would certainly be interesting.

In fact, logic programs allowing the discussed form are called "Disjunctive Logic Programs". This is an active research & engineering direction. See for example the [DLV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLV) system, which is actually based off Datalog, so does not allow function symbols.

Comment: Of course, philosophically speaking, you _can_ do it. You just need to write the appropriate proof system on top of Prolog. Here is a paper from 1998: [Disjunctive Logic Program = Horn Program + Control Program](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221176762_Disjunctive_Logic_Program_Horn_Program_Control_Program). Hmm between two interesting ideas that you don't have the time to study there is another interesting idea that you don't have the time to study either.